# Is there function or possibility to print the digits that have been together in the number?

Tags: arrays, list, digits

I am trying  to code a program about when I enter a digit number(6 different numbers) and if that number is in my array, then print the number. But if the number isn't in our array, print the digits of that number that has been together in any number the in array. For example, I have "1-9-12-17-30-7", "40-30-20-10-15-11" in my array and I enter the number "1-2-3-9-7-12". I want it to prints the digits from the entered number that has been together in numbers in the array. That is "9-7-12".

[image]

Comment: Hi, I suggest you write your code directly in the content section of the question, instead of putting the link of a screen shot.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for storing the numbers as string instead of using a int array? I mean... Are you force to do it that way?